# what do you do these days or what are you doing these days

Tags: present-tense

I haven't seen my friend for a year. When I stumble on him I say
(1)"what are you doing these days" and it's apparently the default choice.

But what if I said: (2) "what do you do these days"? -- I feel that it doesn't change much. Is it slightly less idiomatic?

Comment: I would understand "What do you do?" as meaning "What do you do for a living - what job do you do?", while "What are you doing?" is more general.

Comment: Note: "_When I stumble on him_" I think you mean "When I stumble **into** him" :) Stumble on might mean you tripped over their feet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) What are you doing these days?
> (2) What do you do these days ?

Both are grammatically valid, and in my view reasonably natural, nut there is at least a difference in nuance of meaning.

Sentence (2) might well indicate an inquiry into the person's occupation, job, or profession. Sentence (1) would be asking about the person's daily or regualr activities.